# What to do if a fitting question already exists but for a slightly different platform?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

The question [How do I get rid of the "Battery fully charged, unplug charger" popup screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41081/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-battery-fully-charged-unplug-charger-popup-screen) is very much what I would like to ask too. However, I have a Galaxy-S3 and not a Galaxy Note 2. And 4.1.2 and not 4.0.

From the present answer, it is clear that the answer is not applicable in my case: there is no such option "Battery Full Notification".

What to do in this case?  Reask the question or somehow modify the existing question? After all, I want to avoid being labelled as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case I think you should feel free to ask a separate question since the devices obviously have different features for this.  Bonus points if you link to the existing question and mention why you're asking the new one.